# Adding multiple raster with Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I'm trying to add multiple raster layers to one output raster using addition in the Raster Calculator. The problem is that the output raster only contains data from the smallest of the four raster.

I'm looking for a tool that could make those four raster to the same extent before using Raster Calculator or maybe some expression in the Raster Calculator tool that could make the output raster to the same extent as the biggest of the four rasters.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From raster calculator, choose `Environments -> Processing extent` as you can see below:

[image]

From the drop-down menu, select the image of larger extent.

Comment: Wouldn't you use the image with the "smallest" extent if you wanted them to match? or perhaps my question is better posed as a comment to the OP?